# Merge tags delta-iv and delta4

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

There is a tag [delta-iv](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/delta-iv) (1 question) and a tag [delta4](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/delta4) (9 questions).

I believe they should be merged with one as a synonym.

<sub>I personally think [delta-iv](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/delta-iv) is better than [delta4](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/delta4)</sub>

Comment: All right, I implemented this answer: https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1591/58

The renames and synonyms are complete.

Comment: @called2voyage For questions like these about tag renaming/merge should I tag it as feature-request or as discussion?

Comment: Thanks for asking. I didn't notice your tags. It should be discussion not feature-request. feature-request is when you want SE to add new functionality to the site.

Comment: @called2voyage I updated the tag then. (and for my previous question on the fairing catchers as well)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both representations have widespread usage, but the Roman numerals *are* how it is represented on the official ULA webpage for it. The only major issue is the [delta4-heavy](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/delta4-heavy) tag already exists and would need to be renamed too for consistency.

The only other potential issue (which is pretty minor) is [delta-iv](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/delta-iv) implies a potential [delta-v](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/delta-v) rocket, but that tag is already in use to represent the concept of [delta-v](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta-v) (change in velocity). However, I think the time when a "Delta V" rocket would have been seriously considered is past.

Anyway, I'm down for renaming both tags, but I can see how this might be controversial, so I'm going to offer both options in separate answers.

Answer (score 5):

- Rename [delta4](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/delta4) to [delta-iv](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/delta-iv).
- Make [delta4](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/delta4) and [delta-4](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/delta-4) synonyms.
- Rename [delta4-heavy](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/delta4-heavy) to [delta-iv-heavy](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/delta-iv-heavy).
- Make [delta4-heavy](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/delta4-heavy) and [delta-4-heavy](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/delta-4-heavy) synonyms.

Answer (score 0):

- Merge [delta-iv](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/delta-iv) to [delta4](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/delta4).
- Make [delta-iv](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/delta-iv) a synonym.
- Leave [delta4-heavy](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/delta4-heavy) alone.
- Make [delta-iv-heavy](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/delta-iv-heavy) a synonym.